# Cache variables in dataprovider

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, datagrid, itemrenderer, datagridcolumn

I've got a model class with a bunch of Number variables that change frequently. 
They all dispatch their custom events, thus are bindable.

In my UI, a couple of those class instances are bundled into an ArrayList that serves as the dataprovider for a Spark DataGrid. 
The class variables change perfectly fine, so problem there.

What I'd like to do now is to change the color formatting of those numbers (the corresponding labels in the gridcoloums to be exact) depending on the data that comes in, so to say change in green when the new value is bigger, change to red when the new value is smaller than the old one.

How can I make this work? I though about some sort of caching of the old value and then compare the old and new one. 
Is this the way to do this, if so, how? Or is there another, probably simpler way without the need to cache anything?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit:
Based on the example given by @NoobsArePeople2, this is my current code.
First the DataGrid. The dataProvider is an ArrayList that holds objects of myModel class.

```
<s:DataGrid dataProvider="{_listItems}" >
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
        <s:GridColumn dataField="change" headerText="Change" itemRenderer="tableCell">
        <s:GridColumn dataField="bid" headerText="Bid" itemRenderer="tableCell">
  ...
</s:DataGrid>
```

Now the tableCell renderer;

```
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" width="100%" height="100%">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private var previousData:Number;
        private var labelColor:uint;
                    private var _data:Object;

        override public function set data(value:Object):void {

            previousData = _data;
            _data = Number(value);
            invalidateProperties();
        }

        override protected function commitProperties():void {
            super.commitProperties();

            if(previousData < data) {
                labelColor = 0x40c040;
            } else if (previousData > data){
                labelColor = 0xf05050;
            } else
                labelColor = 0xc0c0c0;

            itemLabel.setStyle("color", labelColor);
            itemLabel.text = String(_data); 
        }   
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Label id="itemLabel"/>
</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

This works fine so far (opposed to using the data property which throws an undefined error), however, when using this very item renderer for multiple grid columns, it uses the same values for each grid column. What's that about?

Edit: Sorry, this works only if I directly address the property of the Model, such like data.property, which I can't do. I need a general item renderer for all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go is a custom item renderer. An [item renderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html) will come with a `data` property (where `data` is a single value from your data provider) that will get set for you when your data provider changes on the DataGrid. You'll want to

1. Add a new private variable `previousData` of type `Object`, and
2. Override the setter for `data` in your item renderer.

Your setter for `data` will look something like this:

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
    // If the data hat not changed, don't do anything
    if (data == value) return;

    // Take the current data and store it in previousData
    previousData = data;

    // Update the current data to the new value that was passed in
    // BEGIN EDIT
    // data = value; <-- Previous code example is wrong it should be:
    super.data = value;
    // END EDIT

    // Tell Flex to update the properties of this renderer
    invalidateProperties();
}
```

Then, in your item renderer, override the `commitProperties()` method like this:

```
override protected function commitProperties():void
{
    super.commitProperties();

    // pseudo code follows
    if (previousData < data)
    {
        labelColor = green;
    }
    else if (previousData > data)
    {
        labelColor = red;
    }
    else
    {
        labelColor = black;
    }

    label.text = data;
    label.color = labelColor;
    // end pseudo code

}
```

Alternatively, if you need to access properties of `data` and don't want to hard code values this should work (note: I haven't actually tested this code, but it should work just fine).

```
override protected function commitProperties():void
{
    super.commitProperties();

    // This assumes your item renderer subclasses [GridItemRenderer][2]
    var dataField:String = column.dataField;
    var previousValue:Object = previousData[dataField];
    var currentValue:Object = data[dataField];

    // pseudo code follows
    if (previousValue < currentValue)
    {
        labelColor = green;
    }
    else if (previousValue > currentValue)
    {
        labelColor = red;
    }
    else
    {
        labelColor = black;
    }

    label.text = data;
    label.color = labelColor;
    // end pseudo code
}
```

Comment: Thanks @NoobsArePeople2 I understand what you're doing here, and basically this is exactly what I thought I needed. However, I've got some small issues with your solution (bare with me here, I haven't really worked with itemrenderers before). First off, the if (data==value) throws an 'undefined' error. Second, the value object will be of type myModel, even though the dataField on the corresponding GridColumn is set to myModel.change, which is a Number. I added my renderer (based on your code) to the initial question above.

Comment: That's because my code sample had a bug. See the part that starts with `BEGIN EDIT`

Comment: Something's really off here. Even though I do get the correct values (including the updates) in my data grid columns WITHOUT the item renderer, a simple trace on value casted to Number in the item renderer always outputs NaN on every update, which I really don't understand as the correct numbers appear for the columns in the data grid without item renderer.

Comment: In your code you are setting the value on `_data`, you need to set it on `data`.

Comment: Got it. However, that does't solve the problem that I'd have to access the Number values via data.propertyOfMyModel, which would mean that I'd have to write item renderers for every single property my model class has. I already thought about accessing the datafield in the gridcoloum from inside the item renderer, but it seems that the spark components do not support that. I'm really lost here.

Comment: If you subclass [GridItemRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/gridClasses/GridItemRenderer.html) you can use its `column` property to get a reference to the [GridColumn](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/gridClasses/GridColumn.html) that the renderer belongs to. `GridColumn` has a property called `dataField` (which you've set) that corresponds to a named property on your data object. You can use this property to access the renderer's `data` properly. I've edited my answer to show this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create your custom item renderer for your data grid. There you should override `data` setter and use [`BindingUtils`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html) to handle field changes. The sample usage is [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cc9.html).

Or you can reassign your data in item renderer the following way:

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
    if (value == data)
        return;
    myModelInstance = MyModelClass(value);
}

[Bindable]
private var myModelInstance:MyModelClass;
```

And then bind to the fields of `myModelInstance` in MXML item renderer.